# What property of uitableviewcell is this?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an option in my app to change the background color. If I select a cell, press the back button, change the color, and select the cell again, this is what happens:

[image: Glitch]

Why does the border thing keep the color from the background of the first time it was selected and how do I fix this? (It resets after the app is closed or anything)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to figure out what are you asking! But...

1 - If you're complaining about the blue selection, you should set the selectionStyle of your cell to None.

2 - If you need some custom selection style, you should override setSelected/setHighlighted.

3 - If you're ok with the blue, but your issue is about keeping selection state, try to deselect the selected row. Inside viewWillAppear.

PS: Always use cell.contentView to set background and stuff.

Comment: do you see the rectangle around the round part of the cell? how would I keep the selection color blue but make that rectangle aroudn the cell like a clear color or at least a color that matches with the background color? (what property is that?)

Comment: Isn't self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]?

If you have a custom UITableViewCell class, you can override prepareForReuse, call super and put this line.

Answer (score 0):

It was the selectedBackgroundView property. UITableViewCellGrouped's selectedBackgroundView property is non-nil by default, so I set it to nil and this glitch was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]

Comment: Please put more effort into your answers than this.